# What is the simplest way to put some text at the beginning of a line and to put some text at the center of the same line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line

I would like that `(H)` be at the left, and `some text` be in the middle of a line. However, the command below does not work since `some text` is at the right.

```
\centerline{(H)\hfill some text}
```

The following can do the job, but is there a more straightforward solution?

```
\centerline{\flushleft{(H)} \centerline{some text}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\hrule % show line width

\noindent\rlap{(H)}\hfill some text\hfill\null\par

\hrule

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`\noindent` starts a new paragraph without indentation of the first line. `\rlap` prints its argument to the right.
The middle text is centered by wrapping it in `\hfill...\hfill`.
The `\null` at the end of the paragraph (`\par`) prevents that TeX removes the previous `\hfill` (TeX removes the last horizontal space at the end of the paragraph).

The `\hfill` at the right side can be replaced by the automatically inserted `\parfillskip`:

```
\noindent\rlap{(H)}\hfill some text{\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}\par}
```

Comment: `\hspace*{\fill}` is much better than using the undocumented `\null`

Comment: @egreg This also adds `\parfillskip`. This can be avoided by the longer `\begingroup\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}\par\endgroup` instead of the right `\hfill`.

Comment: Uh? Usually `\parfillskip` uses `fil` glue.

Comment: Thank you, the border lines was not a part of question.

Comment: @Name The border lines make it easier to see, that `some text` is in the middle of the line.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a fully LaTeX compliant solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\newcommand{\lcrline}[3]{%
  \par % we want to be on a line by itself
  \noindent % no indent
  \makebox[\linewidth][s]{% spread to the line width
    \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}% text at left
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][c]{#2}% text at center
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{#3}% text at right
  }%
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\lcrline{(H)}{some text}{}

\bigskip

\lcrline{Left}{Longer text in the middle}{Right}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Well, also

```
\def\lcrline#1#2#3{\par\hbox to \linewidth{\rlap{#1}\hss#2\hss\llap{#3}}
```

would work essentially the same. Why not using this? Because the above solution only uses documented commands in the LaTeX manual and, in case of a new version is released that breaks the macro above, you can hold it against the maintainers; the other one (similar in spirit to other answer to the present question) would be rejected with “we're responsible only for the documented features”.

An extended version that will warn in case there's overlap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\newcommand{\lcrline}[3]{%
  \par % we want to be on a line by itself
  %%% check for no overlapping
  \checklcrlineoverlap{#1}{#2}{#3}
  \noindent % no indent
  \makebox[\linewidth][s]{% spread to the line width
    \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}% text at left
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][c]{#2}% text at center
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{#3}% text at right
  }%
  \par
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\checklcrlineoverlap[3]{%
  \@tempswafalse
  \settowidth\@tempdima{#1}%
  \settowidth\@tempdimb{#2}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\@tempdima+0.5\@tempdimb>.5\linewidth
    \@tempswatrue
  \fi
  \settowidth\@tempdima{#3}%
  \settowidth\@tempdimb{#2}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\@tempdima+0.5\@tempdimb>.5\linewidth
    \@tempswatrue
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \@latex@warning{Overlap for \protect\lcrline}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lcrline{(H)}{some text}{}

\bigskip

\lcrline{Left}{Longer text in the middle}{Right}

\bigskip

\lcrline{Long long text at the left}{Longer longer text in the middle}{Right}

\bigskip

\lcrline{Left}{Longer longer text in the middle}{Long long text at the right}

\end{document}
```

The terminal and the log file would display

```
LaTeX Warning: Overlap for \lcrline on input line 47.

LaTeX Warning: Overlap for \lcrline on input line 51.
```

Comment: Thank you, the border lines was not a part of question.

Comment: @Name I added them just for showing the alignment; remove the call to `showframe`.

Comment: I used `\hss` because... I don't know. Why in this case is `\hfill` the correct one?

Comment: @Manuel Whatever… But `\hss` is not documented in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\linetext{O{}mO{}}
  {\par\noindent
   \makebox[\textwidth][s]{\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}\hss\makebox[0pt][c]{#2}\hss\makebox[0pt][r]{#3}}}
```

And then use `\linetext[left]{center}[right]` where the first and third arguments are optional, hence you can write `\linetext{center}` or `\linetext[left]{center}` or `\linetext{center}[right]`.

Answer (score 2):

To your choice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\leftline{(H)\hfil some text.}

or precisely

\leftline{\makebox[0pt][l]{(H)}\hfil some text.}

\noindent
(H)\hfil some text.

or precisely

\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{(H)}\hfil some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]